# ASP .NET MVC, Unknown runtime error in IE (nested forms)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

i have view which looks something like this :

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "someDiv", HttpMethod = "Post"))
   {%>

 <%= Ajax.ActionLink("Add new", "AddNewItem", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divAddNewItem", HttpMethod = "Get" })%>

<div id="divAddNewItem">
</div>

  <input type="submit" value="Create" />

<% } %>
```

"AddNewItem" action returns partial view, which is rendered to divAddNewItem, AddNewItem  view code looks like this one :

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divAddNewItem", HttpMethod = "Post"))
   {%>

       <input type="submit" value="Add" />
<% } %>
```

in this case, after clicking "Add new" button IE will give exception (unknown runtime error), while chrome and firefox will work.
i made some research, and it seems like nested form tags causing the problem.

would be glad to hear any possible hint or advice in solving this problem.

Thank You !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested forms are illegal in HTML. You can't do it. IE tends to react worse than Firefox, but you should not do it in either browser.

> [There can be several forms in a single document, but the FORM element can't be nested.](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html)

Comment: so, one of possible solutions would be to delete nested form , and replace submit button with Ajax.ActionLink ?

Comment: Or just un-nest the form. You can have *multiple* forms; they just can't be nested.

Comment: Hi. thanks for reply. If i'll un-nest them there will be some design issues :) . And if I use actionlink(or jquery), i'll need to pass all data to action manually ? (i.e. new { id=textbox1.value, name=textbox2.value } ?

Comment: IMHO it is generally easier to un-nest forms than to bypass them completely. But it's your code, and I haven't seen it, so you'll have to decide that for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer, in instances like this, to make a div which looks like a form (or even a dialog box a la DHTML) and wire up an ajax post of these "form" elements to an onclick event of the button. It's obviously a lot more work, but it's gotten me out of a lot of jams.